# how to use process.hrtime to get execution time of async function

Tags: node.js

I am triing to get execution time of async function. Seemingly I can use [process.hrtime](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.0/api/all.html#all_process_hrtime) for this. I created simple example:

```
console.log("starting");
var start = process.hrtime();
console.log("start");
console.log(start);

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("HELLO");
    var end = process.hrtime();
    console.log("end");
    console.log(end);
}, 1000);
```

It outputs

```
starting
start
[ 131806, 731009597 ]
HELLO
end
[ 131807, 738212296 ]
```

But I don't understand where is exectuion time in miliseconds? I expect to get 1000 ms in this example.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Got it:

```
console.log("starting");
var start = process.hrtime();
console.log("start");
console.log(start);

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("HELLO");
    var end = process.hrtime(start);
    console.log("end");
    console.log(end);
}, 1000);
```

Prints

```
starting
start
[ 132798, 207101051 ]
HELLO
end
[ 1, 7001730 ]
```

That means 1 second and 7001730 nanoseconds from start to end

Answer (score 12):

Since Node 10.7.0, [`process.hrtime`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime) is marked as 'legacy', with the recommended method being [`process.hrtime.bigint`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_bigint). The documentation contains an example of how to use this method to time an operation:

```js
const start = process.hrtime.bigint();
// 191051479007711n

setTimeout(() => {
  const end = process.hrtime.bigint();
  // 191052633396993n

  console.log(`Benchmark took ${end - start} nanoseconds`);
  // Benchmark took 1154389282 nanoseconds
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to add in case someone needs the execution time in ms:

```
console.log("starting");
var start = process.hrtime();
console.log("start");
console.log(start);

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("HELLO");
    var end = process.hrtime(start); // end[0] is in seconds, end[1] is in nanoseconds
    const timeInMs = (end[0]* 1000000000 + end[1]) / 1000000; // convert first to ns then to ms
    console.log("timeInMs:", timeInMs);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple wrapper timing function for async functions:

```
// async function execution time wrapper
async function fnTime(fn, ...params) {
  const start = process.hrtime()
  const result = await fn(...params)
  const end = process.hrtime(start)
  console.log(
    `[${fn.name}] Execution time:${(end[0] * 1000000000 + end[1]) /
      1000000} ms`
  )
  return result
}
```

example usage (see this demo on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@EmmanuelKyeyune/nodeAsyncFunctionExectionTimeWrapper)):

```
// usage
const setTimeoutPromise = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

// example 2:
// get name from db
const db = {
  async getUser(id){
    // simulate wait for record retrival from db
    await fnTime(setTimeoutPromise, 150)

    return {
      _id: id,
      name: 'John Doe',
      organisation: 'UN',
      email: 'johndoe@un.org'
    }
  }
}


// test it
;(async function(){
  const result = await fnTime(db.getUser, 'asfa98th4nfwef0qwrwef0')
  console.log('result', result)
})()

// result:
// [setTimeoutPromise] Execution time:197.928094 ms
// [getUser] Execution time:199.480553 ms
```